# Alter between R studio windows only using the keyboard

Tags: rstudio

I wonder if there is a way to move between the windows in an R studio session only using a keyboard shortcut. For example change the input from the R console to the source window etc.

Comment: you can define that yourself

Comment: Ctrl+1 and Ctrl+2 can do that

Comment: Pressing Ctrl + Shift + K in Rstudio will open a shortcut quick reference which includes shortcuts for moving focus between panes, switching tabs and more.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + K opens the R reporting tool ( at least in my R studio version ), but thanks!

Comment: Oh it's Alt + Shift + K, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + 1` and `Ctrl + 2` by [vanao veneri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233103/vanao-veneri) and for more info try `Alt + Shift + K` by [Marijn Stevering](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5401322/marijn-stevering).